# jQuery plugin for browser that doesn't support placeholders

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Placeholders has always been an issue in IE8 or IE9. As a workaround for this,
I used [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/tree/v1.8.7) that enables placeholder to browsers who does not support this. Since my `jQuery` is 1.5, I used v1.8.7 of that plugin because $.valHooks is undefined. But what happened is that it seemed didn't work since my placeholders doesn't behave properly in IE8/IE9.

I have already included the `jQuery.placeholder.js` in my project and since it was stated there that to invoke this is you use this, `$('input, textarea').placeholder();`. Still i did not work. Are there other ways needed to do before using the plugin.

My placeholder issues are during submission of form and also when replacing the placeholder of 1 textbox.

Your help is greatly appreciated. ;)

Comment: http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using **http://modernizr.com**

It's a plugin which detects features the user's browser supports. If it's not supported, a jQuery plugin makes it happen!